# How to define a function that can detect whether a string is a decimal in Python?

Tags: python, function

The question started because this: I typed `"7.8".isnumeric()` and it returned `False` .
I would like to define a function that can detect whether a string is a decimal in Python. I hope it is like this:

```py
>>> isdecimal("8.2")
True
>>> isdecimal("8.1.8")
False
>>> isdecimal("6.")
True
>>> isdecimal("6.2.")
False
>>> isdecimal("5")
True
>>> isdecimal(".")
False
>>> isdecimal("6 8")
False
>>> isdecimal("foo")
False
>>> isdecimal("-4.")
True
>>> isdecimal("9e+40")
True
>>> isdecimal("-4e-4987")
True
>>> isdecimal("7.3e+18")
True
>>> isdecimal("7.3.1e+18")
False
>>> isdecimal("7.3e+18.5")
False
>>> isdecimal("1/2")
False
```

How to do it?

Comment: What do you know about Python so far? What have you tried? Do you know how to convert strings to number in general? Do you work in the REPL only?

Comment: Have you ever informed yourself what [isnumeric](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric) actually does?

Comment: Stuff it into `float()` and see it it raises an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `isinstance()` like below:

```
def isdecimal(s):
    try:
        if isinstance(float(s), float):
            return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Check:

```
print(isdecimal("8.2"))
print(isdecimal("8.1.8"))
print(isdecimal("6."))
print(isdecimal("6.2."))
print(isdecimal("5"))
print(isdecimal("."))
print(isdecimal("6 8"))
print(isdecimal("foo"))
print(isdecimal("-4."))
print(isdecimal("9e+40"))
print(isdecimal("-4e-4987"))
print(isdecimal("7.3e+18"))
print(isdecimal("7.3.1e+18"))
print(isdecimal("7.3e+18.5"))
print(isdecimal("1/2"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
False
True
False
False
False
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 is this helps you or not?

Comment: You define `s: str`.  So if you really call this function with a string `s` as a parameter, how could `isinstance(s, float)` ever be true?

Comment: No. Did you ignore to do `float(s)`?

Comment: @user1740577 I would like to avoid the strings like `"inf"`, `"nan"`

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 only "inf" and "nan". is this not ok skip this two string?

Comment: @user1740577 Yes. I added the condition to the “if” statement and solved the question.

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 exactly because float("nan")and  float("inf") is float and you need to add condition

Comment: Converting something to a float and then checking if this floating point value is a floating point value doesn't make sense. To make it worse this solution crashes when we enter a value like "8.1.8" that was given in the question. I don't know why this answer was accepted. For future readers: The answer from @Jasmijn is the way to go.

Comment: And if you now remove the superfluous call to `isinstance` and just leave the needed `float(s)` you have exactly the same code as in the other answer. I'm sorry if my previous comment sounded a bit harsh, but there is really no need for `isinstance` here.

Comment: @Matthias if i remove these lines  other user see this two answer are same, and if you read comment, you can see. OP give `accept` because i say if you want  `inf` and 'nan` return false you need add condition because these 'inf' and 'nan' are `float`.

Comment: @user1740577 `isinstance(float('inf'), float)` is true, and the same goes for NaN. The constructor for `float` will always either return an instance of `float` or raise an exception.

Comment: @Jasmijn thanks a lot for your comment. but I'm not good at English and can't understand all of your comments. excuse me, Am I answer anything?

Comment: @Jasmijn I say exactly your comment to the OP but OP says my problem should return false for 'nan' and 'inf' and I say if only these two words you can add condition and return false for these two words. I say : `only "inf" and "nan". is this not ok skip this two string? `

Comment: @user1740577 I wouldn't check for the strings, because there may be variations accepted by `float()` (like capitalization and signs). I would do `return float(s).isfinite()` inside the `try` block.

Comment: @Jasmijn Wow, Thanks a lot, TIL I learn from you. I check for this : `float('nan').isfinite()` got error : `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isfinite'` but this is very good idea.

Comment: @user1740577 That's what I get for not checking... It should have been `math.isfinite(float('nan'))`, apologies!

Comment: @Jasmijn thanks a lot fot both of them :`math.isfinite(float('inf'))
math.isfinite(float('nan'))` I got False. this answer is awesome.

Comment: @Jasmijn do you edit your answer? or do I add this detail to my answer?

Comment: @user1740577 I feel like we shouldn't edit answers that have been accepted. I'll add an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way (if not necessarily the fastest) would be to try to convert the string to a `float`:

```
def isdecimal(s: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

---

Addendum: if you would only want to accept representations of finite floating point numbers, you can use `math.isfinite`, which returns `False` for NaN and (+/-)Inf, as such:

```
import math

def isdecimal(s: str) -> bool:
    try:
        return math.isfinite(float(s))
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: There is a Python library math function called isfinite() that could be used to test for NaN and infinities. There's also the possibility of float() returning an OverflowError for a massive, but valid, decimal string.